# Pointer initialised to null changing to 0x1

Tags: c

Having a bit of trouble with a c program I am having to work on (has to be in c, not c++).

I have a struct typedef called list. I have this function:

```
void init(list * l){
    l=malloc(sizeof(list));
    l->data=NULL;
    l->index=NULL;
    l->next=NULL;

    printf("Pointer= %p\n", (void *) l->next);
}
```

Back in another file, I have this

```
list l;
printf("malloc\n");
init(&l);
printf("Pointer= %p\n", (void *) l.next);
```

The output of this would be (when on the below OS's):

```
malloc
Pointer= (nil)
Pointer= 0x1
```

Can anybody explain to me how this suddenly changes from NULL to 0x1? Its really messing me up when I try to use this as 0x1 obviously doesnt equal null and I eventually get segfaults.

This code works fine on my macbook but on CentOS and Ubuntu 16.04 it generates the above output. 
Is there anyway I can make sure it stays at NULL? am I been stupid?

Thanks

Comment: remove `l=(list *) malloc(sizeof(list));`. then try again.

Comment: Yeah same thing. I added that in with the hopes it made any changes :P I shall remove it from the question anyways

Comment: Remove the `malloc` then show **your entire porogram**. If it's too big reduce it to the bare minimum, see [mcve].

Comment: @Christopher is any of the two first snippets of code beyond your control? That is, any of them cannot be modified?

Comment: @anzurio The code within the init method can be changed by me but the signature or the second snippet are out of my control unfortunately. Removing the malloc does fix this issue :)

Comment: @Christopher OK, Thanks. I will write an answer why is that the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `list l;` already allocates memory for `l`. Such memory's address can be obtained by `&l`.

What you are passing to `init` is essentially a number, an address in memory (e.g., `0x0000`). When `init` gets executed, `l` has the value of the address (`0x0000`). The fact that the type of `l` is `list*`, means that `l` is an address (`*`) to a `list` object.

`malloc` allocates new memory (in this case of `sizeof(list)`) and returns an address (a number) of where that is located. Essentially, the value of `l` has effectively changed because the address provided by `malloc` is a different one from the one where you called `init`.

Removing `malloc` should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! :D  got everything working now

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is either pass a double pointer to `init()`, or have `init()` return the pointer.

In C, all values are passed by *value*. Hence, when you pass the pointer to `init()` you pass a memory location of a `list`. When `init()` executes, the passed value that is in the `l` variable gets overwritten when you call `malloc()`. It does **not** update the passed pointer, however. This still points to the memory location of the local variable `list l`.

Comment: Nope, it is enough to remove the `malloc`.

Comment: I would have liked to do that but the for the program we where given a header file which specifies the signature of the function meaning we cannot change the value it receives or its return values. Automated tests will be fun on it aswell so any changes will break everything i would expect :/

Comment: Then do what @n.m. suggests: remove the malloc, or do it in the `init()`'s caller.

Comment: @n.m. That does seem to fix the issue. Can you explain why it is you dont need to malloc? Does having the list l automatically allocate the required memory? I thought this may have been the case but reading online suggested that malloc was required. Btw,  add it as an answer, I will mark yours as the solution! :)

Comment: @Christopher You already have a list structure `l`. You took its address and passed it to `init`. This means you want to initialize **that** structure, not a completely new structure returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `init` function allocates a new object and fills in values in that object. This new dynamically-allocated object is unrelated to `list l;` which was allocated in `main`.

To avoid confusion I would recommend using a different name for the function parameter than for your variable in `main`, since they potentially may refer to different objects.

If you remove the line `l=malloc(sizeof(list));`, then the rest of the code in `init` will be updating your `list l;` which was defind in `main`, and you should see the expected output.